# Owncloud upload file to specific folder - curl

Tags: curl, owncloud

I want upload files through curl on my owncloud server in a specific folder. For example: `http://www.myowncloudserver.com/remote.php/webdav/{MY_FOLDER}`. At this time I can't upload a file to a folder on my owncloud server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ curl --user username:password -X PUT "https://www.myowncloudserver.com/remote.php/webdav/MY_FOLDER" --data-binary @"file.txt"
```

Comment: you need add file name to target url `https://www.myowncloudserver.com/remote.php/webdav/MY_FOLDER/file.txt`