# How can I script file upload to an owncloud shared link folder?

Tags: curl, jenkins, webdav, owncloud

If I share access to a folder using a (temporary) link, anyone who knows the link and a password can upload files to that folder using the webinterface.

How can I script an upload to an owncloud folder that is shared via link?

For a regular user of the server, who has access to the webdav interface, the question is answered in [Uploading files to an owncloud server programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758167/uploading-files-to-an-owncloud-server-programatically).

My actual use case is to upload build artifacts from a jenkins job. I do not want to use my own user account for security reasons, nor is our IT willing to create a pseudo-user.

Answer (score 5):

```
curl -u token:password -T filename "https://your.owncloud.server/public.php/webdav/filename"
```

The `token` is the string at the end of the shared link (e.g. `abcdefghijk0123` in `https://your.owncloud.server/index.php/s/abcdefghijk0123`). If you don't use a password to protect the link you can leave the field in the command blank.

Comment: It does not work for me. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
I shared a link, as `https://www.vpext.dsa-ac.de/dsacloud/index.php/s/rRLXrewsDIq4aRz` but the upload via `curl -u rRLXrewsDIq4aRz:pwd -T DefaultCatalog.xml "https://www.vpext.dsa-ac.de/dsacloud/public.php/webdav/DefaultCatalog.xml"` returns a `NotAuthenticated` exception.

Comment: Was your shared link reachable via browser at this time? Maybe you could try without password for testing.

Comment: I got it working for the directory name, i.e. not the shared URL token, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37921752/1184842

Comment: Maintained here: https://github.com/ceremcem/owncloud-tools/blob/master/upload.sh

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is still looking for an answer to this question (it was the first google result for me), there is a solution for this in the OwnCloud admin-manual.

If you have not password-protected file drop link like

```
https://example.com/s/70mX9s7KOZwfmdi
```

(token `70mX9s7KOZwfmdi`) you can upload a file `file.txt` from command line with the following cURL command:

> ```
> curl -k -T file.txt -u "70mX9s7KOZwfmdi:" -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \https://example.com/public.php/webdav/file.txt
> ```

Source: https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/user_manual/files/access_webdav.html#uploading-files-to-a-public-link-file-drop-using-curl

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an app password on https://your-owncloud-server/settings/personal#apppasswords, that way you wouldn't need an other user account.

Edit: only works on Nextcloud

Comment: I do not see such an options on my settings page. I do see
`personal#clientsbox`
`personal#passwordform`
`persona#ssl-root-certificates`.